# How do I show just the time part of a date?

Tags: t-sql, datetime

I would like to get just the time portion of a date time using `T SQL`.  I have found that to get different formats you can use something like this:

```
CONVERT(varchar,GETDATE(),108)  ---17:15:00 gives time in 24hr format
```

I would like to get that as 5:00 PM.

Comment: Leave formatting to the application; it's not the RDBMS'es job.

Comment: I wish I could but I can't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of SQL? 2008 and up have several "Time" datatypes, which--if all you need is Time -- is more convenient.

As for layout/presentation, use the `CONVERT` function with the desired formatting code. Here's a sample of how that can work:

```
DECLARE @When time

SET @When = getdate()

PRINT @When
PRINT convert(varchar(10), @When, 100)
```

Comment: I want only the time part...and yes 2008

Comment: My code sample will generate a varchar with the data formatted as (?) you want it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [T-SQL FORMAT function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx).

Here is [the date/time formatting reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Works, if they've got SQL 2012 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

Can't we use any trimming functions just to meet our requirement.

```
DECLARE @Req TIME

SET @Req = '2014-08-04 16:01:08.4231'

SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @Req, 100), 7)
```